# codeigniter - what's wrong with my htaccess?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm trying to build a shopping cart locally using PHP & MySQL. My main directory for my site is /Library/WebServer/Documents. I tried to set it up so that I can access localhost/project without the index.php.

Here's my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

My config code (extracted, not the whole thing):

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Apparently there's an error with this. Even though I managed to access localhost/project without index.php, I can't view pages generated by my controller code (ex. if I try to go to localhost/project/welcome I get this error message: **'The requested URL /project/welcome was not found on this server.'** localhost/project/welcome should take me to the Welcome.php page under my controllers folder.

[Here's a snapshot of the file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XJMG.jpg)

Can someone explain to me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Usually, you wouldn't have `.htaccess` file in `views` directory. At least there is no such a file with fresh CI installation.

Comment: @vnguyen you need to remove index.php from Url ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean without .php?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

OR

remove this DirectoryIndex index.php!
It sets the index.php behind the url

Answer (score 0):

Use this .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```